# C# with Entity Framework Is there a way to implement repository pattern with an abstract base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Instead of an interface, I would like my Repositories to inherit from an abstract class (Base Repository). I decided I wanted to use an abstract class because I won't be unit testing the repositories (I will unit test service layer instead) and i didn't want to copy over the same implementation to every repository class that inherits from this base repository.

For example:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        dbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

When I tried to create other repositories that inherit from this base repository, I get problems with the constructor. How do I pass the datacontext into these derived classes so that they can be used?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the context in the constructor:

```
    public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal MyEntities context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public Repository(MyEntities context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Use:

```
var repo = new Repository<MyClass>(context);
```

Comment: Your example will not work since my base class is abstract. In C#, abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

Comment: don't make it an abstract base class.  Create your repo's in your UnitOfWork class and instance each of them with this Repo class.

Comment: I want to create an abstract base class so that i don't have to add the same implementations to all my repository classes. I don't see the point of creating interfaces since I will only be unit testing the controllers with fake service classes.